# I want to add an id stored in a variable in a jquery appended html code that is indented

Tags: jquery

Say I have this jquery code:
`var myID = 1;`

```
$('.cpb-row-empty-hook').before('' + 
<input type="file" id="bg-image-uploader-"' + bgImageUploadID + ' />
```

I am using + for being able to append indented code with jquery. The problem is that the input is actually rendered in this form:

```
<input type="file" id="bg-image-uploader-" 1 />
```

The number stored in the variable is not added to the id.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('.cpb-row-empty-hook').before('' + 
<input type="file" id="bg-image-uploader-' + bgImageUploadID + '" />
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh! Apparently I was adding those extra " :)

Answer (score 6):

Use [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to create element, It will save you from quotes mess

```
var input = $('<input>', {
    type: "file",
    id: "bg-image-uploader-" + bgImageUploadID
});
$('.cpb-row-empty-hook').before(input);
```

---

However, you need to use quotes wisely

```
$('.cpb-row-empty-hook').before('<input type="file" id="bg-image-uploader-' + bgImageUploadID + '" />')
```